# When I upload a document in Sharepoint others don't see it even though they have permission

Tags: permissions

In our sharepoint subsite, I created a folder in the Document Library and shared it with key people. No one can see what's being shared. Everyone can upload files but no one can see who has uploaded what.

I checked the permission level and key people who need to have full access have Full Control. Still there is no luck. Even Admin level users can't see the files.

help?

Comment: Do you have versioning enabled in this library? Are there required metadata fields on the library that aren't being supplied.

Comment: @EricAlexander - yes auto-enabled; turned out that also "check-out" was auto enabled. I had to make changes in setting for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This often happens when you have the "require checkout" option enabled on the library.
To check this, try uploading a file and see if it immediately gets the little green overlay on its icon, indicating that it is checked out.

From the Library Settings page, click the link to manage files with no checked-in version. You should see a view of all the documents and the option to take ownership and check them in.

Comment: It is true; not sure though why the documents were originally defaulted to 'checked-out'. How do we prevent that? 

The work around came from Susan Hanely's blog which delves a bit deeper as going into changing the setting alone did not initially yielded the desired results; instead I had to take ownership of all the files first. After that, I had to check them all back in. 

Source: http://www.networkworld.com/article/2346678/microsoft-subnet/sharepoint-mystery--the-case-of-the-missing-documents.html

Comment: Hi James. I having this problem as you mentioned above. I upload a file but it shows a little green icon and only me can see the file. How should I do for this?

Comment: You can disable the "require checkout" feature under Library Settings > Versioning Settings. This will make it so that any file you upload will be visible to others automatically.
Alternatively you can simply remember to check in a file immediately after you upload it. This has the benefit that you can continue working on the file while it is in DRAFT mode and check it in when you're ready for others to see your work.