# Unique Permissions messing up users access?

Tags: permissions, unique

Ok, I guess I need a quick brush up on the topic of Unique Permissions. I have a folder which has another folder (JSLib, CSS, Images), and 3 pages:
Folder A
 - Subfolder A JSLib
 - Subfolder B CSS 
 - Subfolder C Images 
 - HTML 1 
 - HTML 2 
 - HTML 3 
Then a bunch of other Lists as web parts.
HTML 1 has it's own unique permission.

So the issue I am having is, folks can see HTML 2 and 3, only a few can see the HTML 1 (exactly how I want it).  However, the images from Subfolder A is showing as a broken link due to permissions (the "X" image) and the Javascripts are not working (accordion, tabs, etc.).  However, I can see all the images and the JavaScript functions are working perfectly for me.

When I broke inheritance from the HTML 1 file to give it a unique permission, did create all the issues for the other users?  I have site owner permission. When I broke inheritance for the HTML 1 and assigned the folks into it's permissions group, they are also having issues.

Hopefully this makes sense, I thought this breaking inheritance permissions was pretty straight forward, but I may be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my response to the @Pradeep.  It wasn't permissions issues.  All the images and scripts that I uploaded were automatically set as ***"Checked Out"***.  Once I checked them all in, it worked.  The solution was from @james on the following post:

***[When I upload a document in Sharepoint others don't see it even though they have permission](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166933/when-i-upload-a-document-in-sharepoint-others-dont-see-it-even-though-they-have)***

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the permissions for the subfolders (JSLib,CSS,Images) for those users who are facing issues in the HTML1 file..

may be the users are not having proper permission to the subfolders in which your css,js is placed..

Comment: thanks for the reply.  It looks like they all have the same permissions.  I just don't understand this SharePoint Permissions.  If someone has access to the Parent, you inherit the parent, you should have permissions..correct?  I can see everything, yet everyone else can't.  I just have to find out where this is breaking.  I've always had this issue with SharePoint...weird permissions issues.

Comment: Hi, I found out what my problem was.  The solution was found by a poster named James.  Here is his answer [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166933/when-i-upload-a-document-in-sharepoint-others-dont-see-it-even-though-they-have).  The individual images and scripts uploaded as _**Checked Out**_ automatically.  I had to go in and check them all in.  Now it's working for everyone.